# Submitting a form with an iFrame target

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, forms, iframe

I want to submit a form into an iFrame on the same page as the form.
I'm using Target="iframe_results" where iframe_results is the name of the iframe.

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome but in IE it pops open a new tab/window.

I tried using JavaScript to do the submits (as outlined in other sources) but this still didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

What version of IE are you using? I've implemented this method without having any issues whatsoever

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

```
<form id="file_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
<input name="file" id="file" size="27" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload" /><br />
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>


function init() {
    document.getElementById('file_upload_form').onsubmit=function() {
        document.getElementById('file_upload_form').target = 'upload_target'; //'upload_target' is the name of the iframe
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work in IE8. This form lives in an iframe in a Facebook App. See here: http://apps.facebook.com/readinglist/

Comment: No worries man. I'll keep on testing different ideas till I solve it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963202/html-form-target-directed-to-ifram-working-in-ff-but-not-ie

Comment: My problem was: you need to have the attribute "name" on the iframe